# Linux: emulate mouse clicks with keyboard

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse

How can I emulate a mouse click on a keyboard on linux, e.g. by defining that my right CTRL-key should behave as if I clicked the right mouse button?

Comment: Check https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/496515/how-to-map-mice-buttons-via-keyboard-linux/571601#571601

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a "use numeric keypad as mouse" option for both kde and gnome. In kde 4.4 it's located under system settings -> Mouse -> Mouse navigation. I think that it's under accessability settings in gnome. The click actions appears on the keys around the numpad - the "+" key is right click and the "5" key is left click in kde.

If you don't run kde/gnome or want to use a more configurable solution, some sort of combination of these two programs should work:

http://www.semicomplete.com/blog/geekery/xdo.html

http://www.nongnu.org/xbindkeys/xbindkeys.html

Use xbindkeys to bind a keypress to

```
   echo "click 3" | xdo
```

in order to get a right click.

Comment: In KDE 4.7 this has been moved and renamed slightly:  Hardware | Input Devices | Mouse | Mouse Navigation | Move pointer with keyboard.

Thanks for the tip! Solved my problem perfectly (only have a stylus with no buttons...)

Comment: xdo doesn't seem to do the trick for me, but `xdotool click 3` does.

Comment: In KDE plasma 5.27.4, the option to use the number pad for mouse navigation is under System Settings > Accessibility > Mouse Navigation

Answer (score 11):

You can create shortcuts in `Keyboard > Custom Shortcuts` and add the xdotool commands. For example:

```
Super + Z -> xdotool click 1 # left click
Super + X -> xdotool click 2 # middle click
Super + C -> xdotool click 3 # right click
```

Comment: Does this keep the mouse button in pressed state until the keyboard keys are released?

Comment: unfortunately not

Answer (score 3):

In CentOS 6.4 it's here:

System Menu --> Preferences --> Keyboard --> Mouse Clicks (tab) --> Enable the Keyboard to Emulate the Mouse (checkbox)

Now use the keypad '5' to left click (the other keypad numbers move the mouse).

[Mouse Preferences (linuxtopia.org)](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_desktop_guides/gnome_2.14_user_guide/prefs-keyboard-a11y.html#goscustaccess-TBL-12)